# React and react native: Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected.ts(1068)

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm studying react-native. I have a problem I cannot solve it. State in react class component gives me error: unexpected token. But useState in functional component works fine. Sorry for my language. I'm from Mongolia.
Here is my class and functional component:
[react-native-class-component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MoePJ.png)

[react-native-functional-component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzPbm.png)

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here in your class component you need to declare your state inside constructor like this

```
 export default class Home extends Component{
         constructor(props){
            this.state = {}
         }
         render(){
             return(
                 <View>
                       <Text></Text>
                 </View>
              )
         }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But in this example:https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-app-intro-slider. It doesn't declare constructor function. Please tell me difference.

Comment: You can declare state without using constructor as well only the difference is when inside constructor the initialization is done through constructor and it is part of the react lifecycle on another hand if it is declared inside class it is part of the class property
and correct syntax for declaring all the different states is explained in this link https://betterstack.dev/blog/four-ways-to-initialize-react-state/#heading-initialize-state-as-a-class-property

Answer (score 0):

The way you have declared the state in your class component is wrong. It should be within your constructor.

```
export default class Home extends Component{
       constructor(props){
            this.state = {}
         }
         render(){
             return(
                 …
              )
         }
    }
```